# Python Syntax, value if else

Tags: python, syntax

Saw this line in a Leetcode solution:

```
top_element = stack.pop() if stack else '#'
```

I understand what is happening, but what is the syntax called? Is this a ternary operator? Just want to understand to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's officially called [Conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in python 3 documentation. Usually it's also called ternary operator, ternary conditional operator or something like that.